# How do I detect if page viewer is the current session

Tags: php, session, user-profile

I'm trying to have a universal "Accounts" page that displays user profiles based on who is viewing it. If as a signed in user, this is my page, content served reflects my ownership. I tried something like

```
<title>
<?php
if ($_SESSION["first_name"]) { //this $_SESSION["first_name"] = $_COOKIE["first_name"]?
?> My Profile </title>
<?php
}
else
?>
User's Profile </title> <!--This line is wrong-->
```

But it does not do what I want it to. Also, that last line `User Profile`, does it mean I have to create a unique index page for each user? I *thought* PHP can dynamically make it possible to view a user's profile without doing a file write  at each sign up?

Comment: r u saving current user info in `$_COOKIE["first_name"]` ?

Comment: @devpro on sign up I save it to cookies but on login, I use sessions instead. My sessions variable contains the boolean of whether or not the input matches what I have in my db i.e ```if (isset($_SESSION["first_name"])) {
 header("Location:my-site");
}
else {
 $_SESSION["first_name"] = auth_user($email, $password);
 header("Location:my-site/");
}```

Comment: is it not working? `if (isset($_SESSION["first_name"]))` or any error r u getting, use error_Reporting.

Comment: did u checked `print_r($_SESSION);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i cant understand ur question but its my guess that u need this .

```
 $user_id = //user id from db of current viewing user 
 if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $user_id)
 {
    echo 'My profile';
 }
 else
 {
    echo 'user profile';
 }
```

Comment: You mean like this `
 $page_owner = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE first_name=$_SESSION['first_name']";
 if ($_SESSION["first_name"] = $page_owner) {
 ?>` ? Would definitely return true and that shouldn't be

Comment: No, thats not when u log in u set your user_id in session then from users list the user u click get his id then match

Comment: Should every new user have their own folder and index.html? So we can check if user id of that index.html matches current session user id. That's the question. Can't they all use a universal index.html page that dynamically serves content?

Comment: like this? 
 `$current_page_name = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE first_name=" . $this->name;
 $current_viewer = $_SESSION['first_name'];
 
 $query = $mysqli->query($current_page_name);
 while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc) {
  if ($row["first_name"] = $current_viewer) {
  ?>
   <h2> My Profile </h2>
 <?php
  }
  else
  ?> -->
  <h2> User Name </h2>
 <?php
 }
 ?>`